# Django file upload...why is this working?

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload

This is the first time I've tried to upload a file with Django.  I did something and it worked, though I realized later that it's not the correct way to do it.  When I called save on the object, did it call a built-in handler for the FileField?  I realize that I should create my own handler but I was just curious why this worked.

```
def upload_test(request):
user=User.objects.get(pk=user.id)
photoform=PhotoForm()
if request.method=='POST':
    photoform=Post_PhotoForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if photoform.is_valid():
        photo=photoform.save(commit=False)
        photo.user=user
        photo.save()
        return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('%s' %photoform.errors)
return render_to_response("site/upload_test.html", {'photoform':photoform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is saving the object and uploading the file to the directory specified in the FileField.

If I create a handler which writes the file in chunks, how can I also save the photoform instance? Will it create duplicates?

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: what do you mean by "handler which writes the file in chunks"?

Comment: def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()

Comment: ok, I was confused, so in your code you have a default handler for saving a files, this work by default, because is handled by a form. Your own handlers can work on request.FILES (e.g. without form itself).

Comment: can you post more info about your model and forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine `PhotoForm` is a `ModelForm`? Manual handling of uploaded files as described in the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads) is only required for standard `Form`s. The chunk handling is performed in the background by the `models.FileField` and its `storage` object, etc.

Comment: just saw this.  Thanks drMeers, I assumed as much but wanted to make sure.